# can't exec 'codesign' (No such file or directory)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I get this error when tying to run an app on a device with Xcode 5

here is the full error

```
CodeSign /Users/Nevo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RecipesBook-efcrcmgnkaitsqaxahtumfbdxtmb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RecipesBook.app
    cd "/Users/Nevo/Desktop/RecipesBook for ios 7 and 6"
    setenv CODESIGN_ALLOCATE "/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate"
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin‭:‬‭/‬usr/bin‭:/‬bin‭:/‬usr/sbin‭:/‬sbin"
    Using code signing identity "iPhone Distribution: Shay Shalev (QN94KCWC64)" and provisioning profile "ProfileRecipeBook" (52D189D8-2FFD-4939-A3C6-1CD1F8B645E0)
    codesign --force --sign 4F0E5397A87B47EE07EC3288681661CBCBB4781C --resource-rules=/Users/Nevo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RecipesBook-efcrcmgnkaitsqaxahtumfbdxtmb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RecipesBook.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /Users/Nevo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RecipesBook-efcrcmgnkaitsqaxahtumfbdxtmb/Build/Intermediates/RecipesBook.build/Debug-iphoneos/RecipesBook.build/RecipesBook.xcent /Users/Nevo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RecipesBook-efcrcmgnkaitsqaxahtumfbdxtmb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RecipesBook.app

error: can't exec 'codesign' (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: I have this same error, have you found anything?  Seems like a path issue.

Comment: Duplicate with more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838378/xcode-5-error-cant-exec-codesign-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: I see you have a space in your Xcode app name. Some scripts have a hard time dealing with spaces, so I would suggest removing it. I don't know if that's what is actually causing the issue though, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 5):

I copied `codesign` from `/usr/bin/` 
to:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/u‌​sr/bin`

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem, thanks for the help.  The issue was with my path.  I had set my path via /etc/launchd.conf and I was driving myself insane trying to edit my path via ~/.bashrc etc. Make sure /usr/bin is in the path that xcode picks up. This page reminded me:
http://overwatering.org/blog/2012/08/setting-path-osx-mountain-lion/

Comment: Could you please explain how that link worked for you? I'm getting: setenv: command not found

Comment: you can't run setenv in terminal, you need to make sure your path includes codesign.  run "which codesign", then make sure your $PATH includes that.

Comment: here's what i did,, which codesign
/usr/bin/codesign
Abdullahs-MacBook-Pro:~ abdullahumer$ cat $PATH
cat: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin: No such file or directory
Abdullahs-MacBook-Pro:~ abdullahumer$ PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/codesign
Abdullahs-MacBook-Pro:~ abdullahumer$ cat $PATH
cat: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/codesign: No such file or directory

Comment: Xcode's path is not the same as your terminal path.  It could be changed elsewhere. check /etc/launchd.conf and ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist as mentioned in the link

Comment: ok its done now. I copied codesign from /usr/bin/ to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin and it worked for me.

Comment: fixing the path is what you should do

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newb with cpp so I am sure that this solution won't work for everyone and I am sure there are many reasons not to do this in certain situations.

My solution was to disable signing:

Build settings >> Signing >> Code Signing Identity >> set this to "Don't Code Sign"