# Qt Creator not compiling Qt Examples for iOS

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, qt

I'm trying to compile one QT Example included in QT creator for iOS device. The example is stocqt and I have getting the following trace when I try to build:

```
error: can't exec '/Applications/Xcode' (No such file or directory)
```

I'm compiling using the following environment:

- Yosemite (10.10.3)
- XCode 6.4
- Qt Creator 3.5.1
- Qt 5.4.2
- Target: iPad with iOS 7.1.1

My PATH in system environment is the following:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Any idea about why Qt Creator is not getting my XCode path or what's going on with it?

Of course, the project is configured for iOS and is using clang.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 5 "error: can't exec 'codesign' (No such file or directory)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838378/xcode-5-error-cant-exec-codesign-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @demonplus Thanks for the feedback. Please read the question above, is about QT Framework, not an issue signing the app and bad path of codesign

Comment: I think you need to install Xcode Command Line Tools, which are not included in Xcode but installed separately, if I remember well need from app store.

Comment: I just have installed it but not working

Comment: I need to add that configuring the same project for OsX, the application can be compiled and launched without issues

Comment: @jgd : I have the same problem  with QT in Mac it shows ,":-1: error: /Applications/Xcode: No such file or directory" I couldn't get the problem.