# build failed xcode can't exec 'codesign'

Tags: xcode, codesign

I get this error when trying to run an app on a device with Xcode 5

error: can't exec 'codesign' (No such file or directory)

I was googling for two days and find nothing.

I look at the question here too and nothing works for me.

here is the full error:

CodeSign /Users/chana/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Help-drsymbthpuqglxbvcobnqddtsvep/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Help.app
    cd /Users/chana/Documents/xcode/Help
    setenv CODESIGN_ALLOCATE /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin‭:‬‭/‬usr/bin‭:/‬bin‭:/‬usr/sbin‭:/‬sbin"
    Using code signing identity "iPhone Developer: Yisroel Dov Schloss (NG5B48CCYR)" and provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" (9E06834D-2BA6-4C56-8FC7-DF3C4406C069)
    codesign --force --sign DB496AB61FA79D8F561DAA41317A98234CB213BB --resource-rules=/Users/chana/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Help-drsymbthpuqglxbvcobnqddtsvep/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Help.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /Users/chana/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Help-drsymbthpuqglxbvcobnqddtsvep/Build/Intermediates/Help.build/Debug-iphoneos/Help.build/Help.xcent /Users/chana/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Help-drsymbthpuqglxbvcobnqddtsvep/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Help.app

error: can't exec 'codesign' (No such file or directory)

Comment: possible duplicate of [can't exec 'codesign' (No such file or directory)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828576/cant-exec-codesign-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: right, i see that, but nothing helps me there